# video gets hidden via javascript but already starts to play (autplay-mode) even it's not visible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, embed, autoplay

i wanted to find a simple method to get a custom preview-image to my videos within my blog by hiding them and make them visible right after click on the preview-image. the user Dominic Green helped me to get it started with the following code. the problem is: the video already starts to play (even if it is hidden) in autoplay-mode right after the page load but i want to have the autoplay to start right after click on the preview-image...

here's my code:

```
<!doctype html>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function(){
$(".video").hide();

$(".loader").click(function(){
$(this).hide();
$(this).parent().find(".video").show();
});
});
```

```
    #container .post .postimg img{
        width:100%;
        height:auto;
        }
    #container .post .postvideo{
        position:relative;
        display:block;
        width:100%;
        height:430px;
        background-color:#0F3;
        }
        #container .post .postvideo .con{
            position:absolute;
            top:0;
            left:0;
            height:100%;
            width:100%;
            z-index:1;
            }
        #container .post .postvideo .video{
            background-color:#C00;
            }
            #container .post .postvideo .video iframe{
                width:100%;
                height:100%;
                }
        #container .post .postvideo .loader{
            background-color:#06C;
            }
        #container .post .postvideo .loader img{
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
            }
```

```
<div class="post">
    <div class="postvideo">
        <div class="con video">
            <iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/v_MVwUqrwDc?rel=0&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
        <div class="con loader">
          <img src="http://cache2.allpostersimages.com/p/LRG/27/2728/9CKND00Z/poster/gulin-darrell-pansy-flowers-floating-in-bird-bath-with-dew-drops-sammamish-washington-usa.jpg" width="758" height="388">
      </div>
    </div>
</div><!--! end of .post -->

<div class="post">
    <div class="postvideo">
        <div class="con video">
        <iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/29017795?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=a80101&amp;autoplay=1" width="460" height="259" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
        </div>
        <div class="con loader">
          <img src="http://cache2.allpostersimages.com/p/LRG/27/2728/9CKND00Z/poster/gulin-darrell-pansy-flowers-floating-in-bird-bath-with-dew-drops-sammamish-washington-usa.jpg" width="758" height="388">
      </div>
    </div>
</div><!--! end of .post -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use,

[YouTube JavaScript Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference/)

Alternatively,

Put this as url (`autoplay off`)

```
http://www.youtube.com/embed/v_MVwUqrwDc?rel=0&autoplay=0"
```

And on click of button change src to

```
http://www.youtube.com/embed/v_MVwUqrwDc?rel=0&autoplay=1"
```

This wont be as smooth as js api, but will do the trick.

Comment: I've included the link to use youtube javascript player api. Work on it, if you find any problems, do let me know :)

Comment: this may be a language problem but i don_t know what you mean?!? how did you do it literally? could you give me an example to the javascript?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use youtube API or vimeo API, I'd suggest you have iframe src empty and set it when the loader div is clicked. so

I will use

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

and

```
<div class="con loader" data-iframe-src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/v_MVwUqrwDc?rel=0&autoplay=1">
```

then in click event of js code, just set the data-iframe-src value to iframe src:

```
$(this).parent().find(".video iframe").attr("src", $(this).attr("data-iframe-src"));
```